# Erase-remove segfaults, but erasing in loop works

Tags: c++, stdvector

Im getting a Segfault at this line:

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(),elem.end(),
         [](Elem  * elem ){return elem->busy_ == false ;}));
```

Investigating with gdb brought:

```
(gdb) print v.begin()
$6 = 0x842b120
(gdb) print v.end()
$7 = 0x0
(gdb) print v.back()
$8 = (Elem *) 0x842b120
```

Valgrind does not detect any problems (except for the segfault).
I exchanged the code in question for:

```
    auto begin = v.begin();
    while( begin != v.end() )
     {
        if((*begin)->busy_ == false) begin=v.erase(begin);
        else begin++;
     }
```

what am I missing?

Comment: The erase-remove idiom uses the two-parameter form of erase. Typo?

Comment: Also, why use a pointer instead of a reference? If you're using idiomatic C++, a const-reference makes a lot more sense in the lambda there.